# Show search history

Tags: feature-request, search

We recently searched a broad series of topics and found several promising leads, some of which we viewed, some of which we wanted to study for later. It would be nice to go back to this search history.

Similar to Google, and the old classic: LexisNexis.

Oh man, do I feel old...

Comment: You should have marked those *we wanted to study for later* links as favorites.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra You can't really favorite groups of posts, which sounds like what the OP wants to do. Someone might be thinking "The first ten here look interesting, let's look at them more in depth later". I can see the practicality of the feature, I just wonder how many would actually use it.